# merge [shortcut], [shortcuts] and [keyboard-shortcuts] on superuser

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

On superuser we have

```
[keyboard-shortcuts] x 34
[shortcuts] x 4
[shortcut] x 2
```

I was thinking of changing the 6 ones labeled shortcuts and shortcut to keyboard-shortcuts as this would be the least work and only take a minute (retagging 4 questions). But I'm not sure. I think shortcuts is maybe better (are there other than 'keyboard-' shortcuts?).

So I'm asking the community... how should this be retagged?

**Edit**: Apparently (thanks Shog9) there is a difference in meaning between 'keyboard-shortcut' and 'shortcut' tout-court (the latter being e.g. a shorthand for instance to type into the Firefox address bar). So the only problem that remains now: should we take 'shortcut' or 'shortcuts' for that last meaning? [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6752/merge-singular-and-plural-tags) doesn't give a decisive answer towards tags being plural or singular.

**Another Edit**: Ok, I've updated the tags, so now there's only 'keyboard-shortcuts' and 'shortcuts'. But I like Jeff Yates' idea of separating 'keyboard-shortcuts' in 'keyboard' and 'shortcuts'. Can this be done with the moderator tools?

Answer (score 9):

[shortcut](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/shortcut) is not currently used for questions related to keyboard shortcuts.
[One question](https://superuser.com/questions/5022/windows-how-to-create-a-shortcut-for-the-safely-remove-hardware-dialog) tagged [shortcuts] also refers to a different meaning for that word.

Proceed carefully...

Comment: Agreed, not all shortcuts on SU relate to the keyboard.

Comment: It's only one. Just delete it. There are so many of them, who will miss one question?

Comment: Heh... I'd have just edited them, but have no power to edit anything not CW on SU. Kinda like Jeff Yates' suggestion though.

Answer (score 4):

I favor `[keyboard-shortcuts]`, too.  It's more descriptive, it contains the other terms (so it will show up in the suggestion box), and it is most frequently used.  Seems like a clear winner to me.

Comment: I don't think "more descriptive" is a valid reason. C#-with-net-35-and-linq-to-xml is more descriptive, but it's also not what we want tags to be.

Answer (score 2):

I vote for separating <kbd>keyboard-shortcuts</kbd> into <kbd>keyboard</kbd> and <kbd>shortcuts</kbd>.

<kbd>shortcuts</kbd> is a category and <kbd>keyboard</kbd> is a subcategory. Of course, in theory, this seems the most sensible to me but in practise, it might be a pain to enforce.

Comment: +1 Yes. This seems a good option indeed!